# Residue Theorem for Gamma Function times Hurwitz Zeta function

Tags: special-functions, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta, line-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I am trying to evaluate an integral which is a product of three functions:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} ds \,\left(\tilde{\beta}\sqrt{2r}\right)^{-s}\, \Gamma(s)\,\zeta_{H}\left(\dfrac{s}{2},\dfrac{1}{2r}\right)
$$
We know that $\Gamma$ has simple poles at the non-positive integers $-n$. The residue is well known and it is given by,
$$
2\pi i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
$$
we notice that the condition for the convergence of the series $s/2 > 1 $ implies $ c > 2$. It can be analytically continued to the whole complex plane with one singularity, a simple pole with residue 1 at $s = 1$. I end up to something like this
$$
-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2r} + \frac{1}{2r\tilde{\beta}^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\sqrt{2r})^n}{n!} \zeta_{H}\left(\dfrac{-n}{2},\dfrac{1}{2r}\right)
$$
I am not sure I got the correct result. Can someone help and check my work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica gives the following result where the first term is the residue as $s=2$:

---

$$\frac{1}{\beta ^2 r}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \left(\beta  \left(-\sqrt{2 r}\right)\right)^n}{n!}\zeta_H\left(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2 r}\right)$$

---

Here's a table of evaluations which is the basis for the formula above.

---

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{Residue[($\beta $}\sqrt{2r})^{-s}\text{Gamma[s]HurwitzZeta[}\frac{s}{2},\frac{1}{2r}\text{],$\{$s,n$\}$]} \\
 -10 & \frac{\beta ^{10} r^5 \zeta \left(-5,\frac{1}{2 r}\right)}{113400} \\
 -9 & -\frac{\beta ^9 r^{9/2} \zeta \left(-\frac{9}{2},\frac{1}{2 r}\right)}{11340 \sqrt{2}} \\
 -8 & \frac{\beta ^8 r^4 \zeta \left(-4,\frac{1}{2 r}\right)}{2520} \\
 -7 & -\frac{\beta ^7 r^{7/2} \zeta \left(-\frac{7}{2},\frac{1}{2 r}\right)}{315 \sqrt{2}} \\
 -6 & \frac{1}{90} \beta ^6 r^3 \zeta \left(-3,\frac{1}{2 r}\right) \\
 -5 & -\frac{\beta ^5 r^{5/2} \zeta \left(-\frac{5}{2},\frac{1}{2 r}\right)}{15 \sqrt{2}} \\
 -4 & \frac{1}{6} \beta ^4 r^2 \zeta \left(-2,\frac{1}{2 r}\right) \\
 -3 & -\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2} \beta ^3 r^{3/2} \zeta \left(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2 r}\right) \\
 -2 & \beta ^2 r \zeta \left(-1,\frac{1}{2 r}\right) \\
 -1 & -\sqrt{2} \beta  \sqrt{r} \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2 r}\right) \\
 0 & \zeta \left(0,\frac{1}{2 r}\right) \\
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & \frac{1}{\beta ^2 r} \\
 3 & 0 \\
 4 & 0 \\
 5 & 0 \\
 6 & 0 \\
 7 & 0 \\
 8 & 0 \\
 9 & 0 \\
 10 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

---

Note the formula and table above both use $\beta$ instead of $\tilde{\beta}$ which would have required extra work to edit the results above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (or prove with the residue theorem or the Fourier inversion theorem) that $$\frac1{2i\pi} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(s)x^{-s}ds = e^{-x}$$ to get that for $c > 2,x>0,a>0$ $$\frac1{2i\pi} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(s)x^{-s}\sum_{n\ge 1} (n+a)^{-s/2}ds = \sum_{n\ge 1} e^{-x \sqrt{n+a}}$$
This is a complicated function, but it extends analytically and most asymptotics should be tractable.

Comment: Actually, the integral I obtained and posted above was the evaluation of an infinite sum st $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta \sqrt{an+b}}$.